# Jquery function is working with button but not with div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I am dynamically creating the tabs. I have created a button **removeTabs** to remove the tabs. It works fine but when i tried to do it with a div **x**it is not working..

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input type='button' id='addTab' value='Add Tab'>
    <input type='button' id='removeTab' value='RemoveTab'>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var index = 0;
    index++;

    $("#addTab").live ('click',function() {
        index++;
        var title = 'Tab.....  ' + index + ' <p title="close" id="removeTab" style="cursor: pointer; display: inline" >x</p>';
        var url = '#fragment-'+index;
        addTab(url,title,index);
    });

    function addTab(url, title, index) {    
        $('#tabs').tabs("add",url,title,[index]);
    }

    $('#removeTab').live('click',function() {
        var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
        var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
        alert(selected);
        $('#tabs').tabs("remove" , [selected] );        
    });
});
```

​
It is not working when I click on **x**

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6VrwD/23/

Comment: sidenote : live() is not necessary here: use `on()` or `bind()` instead

Comment: I have used but it did not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `tabTemplate` option for this, just like in the demo they provide:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <p title='close' id='removeTab' style='cursor:pointer;display:inline'>x</p></li>"
    });
});
```

... And then just slightly tweak the rest of your JS:

```
$(function() {
    var index = 0;
    index++;

    $("#addTab").live('click', function() {
        index++;
        var title = 'Tab.....  ' + index;
        var url = '#fragment-' + index;


        addTab(url, title, index);

    });

    function addTab(url, title, index) {

        $('#tabs').tabs("add", url, title, [index]);
    }


    $('#removeTab').live('click', function() {
        var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
        var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
        alert(selected);
        $('#tabs').tabs("remove", [selected]);
    });
});​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/6VrwD/27/

Also, you may want to use classes instead of ids on the generated tabs. Having multiple elements with the same `id` attribute on a page is invalid and will probably cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have more than one element with the same id.  Try using a specific class like `add-tab` and `remove-tab`.

***edit 1:***

I appears as though your problem relates to the tab rendering the `<p>` tag in the anchor.  You can probably get away with adding the `X` after the anchor and *then* binding the click event.

***edit 2:***

First time I come across the jqueryui tabs :) --- it appears as though you need a tabTemplate as per this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation

Comment: take a look at the jQuery UI Documentation with this demo... http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation